# How can I tell my last successful logon time and # of failures since last logon as a standard user on a stand-alone system without reducing security?

Tags: windows, security, login, authentication

I want to report, via a popup, when the user's last successful logon time and the number of failures since the last successful logon time were.

I'm aware that there is a policy setting to perform this very thing but it only works in Active Directory environments and I need this to work on stand-alone systems.

I'm also aware that this information is in the Security event log but you must be an Administrator to be able to query the Security log so that doesn't help.

I tried to get around this by writing a script that would run a scheduled task as System on every users' logon event so I could query the Security event log but then my user context is lost for knowing the actual standard user logging in.

So... is there a way for a standard user to read the Security event log without re-ACLing stuff to reduce security?

Comment: Stand alone systems can still be configured to use a group policy.  There is no method to provide non-Administrator access to the event logs, without giving them access to the event logs.

Comment: Policy isn't the problem, it's that the existing policy to have Windows do it for you reads and writes to AD computer object attribs, which obviously don't exist in a stand alone scenario.

Comment: It appears there's no easy way to do this--which seems a little odd.  Seems like an architectural problem that a user can't natively know details of his own logon events.  Regardless, I'm fixing this in a two-part process.  A Scheduled Task, running as System to read the Security log and dump users' logon events to their profile directory.  A second script, running at logon with user credentials to read their own file to determine this data.